# Is it possible to change private key

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I would like to know if it's possible to change private key of bitcoin wallet via rpc call to bitcoind.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

No, your public key are generated from your private key it cannot be changed.

Private key have one public key and each public key have one adress

Comment: I would also add that Bitcoin core uses a list of private keys, so unintentionally private keys vary for privacy

Answer (score 1):

Which key do you want to change? A wallet stores your private keys of your `UTXOs`. You could change your private key, if you are able to find a hash collision with another (Private,Public)-Key-Pair that equals the `OP_HASH160(Orig_Pub_Key) == OP_HASH160(HASHCOLLISIONPUBKEY)`.
Hopefully, this is not possible in a finite time...

If it is about your own wallet password, of course you can do that. The only information that is important is your (Pub,Priv)-Keypair. Don't forget that you need the public key too, to unlock your coins!